# Dockerized integration test an ASP.NET Core app connection to RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I have very new to the dockerized integration testing world, so my apologies in advance if the question sounds very trivial.

I have an ASP.NET Core app that communicates with a dockerized RabbitMQ instance. When I start the application for debugging, `docker-compose` creates an container of that app and RabbitMQ, and then app is able to establish a connection to the RabbitMQ service. However, when running integration tests, the app fails to establish connection to the RabbitMQ service.

I do have a separate `docker-compose` for the integration tests that starts the RabbitMQ service, which I run it before running integration tests.

The test and application setup is fairly simple and follows a common setup, and is defined as:

```cs
public class WebAPITest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    public WebAPITest(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task IfConsumerReceives()
    {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/requestitems");

        // assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

The application has a RabbitMQ service, defined as it follows in the `Startup` class:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    RegisterEventBus(services);
    services.AddOptions();
}

private void RegisterEventBus(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IRabbitMQPersistentConnection>(sp =>
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:HostName"],
            Port = Configuration.GetValue<int>("RabbitMQConnection:Port"),
            DispatchConsumersAsync = true
        };

        factory.UserName = Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:UserName"];
        factory.Password = Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Password"];
        var retryCount = int.Parse(Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:RetryCount"]);
        return new DefaultRabbitMQPersistentConnection(factory, logger, retryCount);
    });

    var queueName = Configuration["QueueName"];
    services.AddSingleton<IEventBus, EventBusRabbitMQ>(sp =>
    {
        var rabbitMQPersistentConnection = sp.GetRequiredService<IRabbitMQPersistentConnection>();
        var iLifetimeScope = sp.GetRequiredService<ILifetimeScope>();
        var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<EventBusRabbitMQ>>();
        var eventBusSubcriptionsManager = sp.GetRequiredService<IEventBusSubscriptionsManager>();

        var retryCount = int.Parse(Configuration["RabbitMQConnection:RetryCount"]);

        return new EventBusRabbitMQ(rabbitMQPersistentConnection, logger, iLifetimeScope, eventBusSubcriptionsManager, queueName, retryCount);
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IEventBusSubscriptionsManager, InMemoryEventBusSubscriptionsManager>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
    ConfigureEventBus(app);
}

private void ConfigureEventBus(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // The following fails to establish connection to RabbitMQ when running integration tests.
    var eventBus = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IEventBus>();
    eventBus.Subscribe<CollectionCompletedIntegrationEvent, CollectionCompletedIntegrationEventHandler>();
}
```

The error message I receive is:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'

Any suggestions is warmly appreciated.

---

### Update 1

As requested docker compose files are as it follows; however, I am not sure these files are called when running integration tests, they are called when debugging only.

- `docker-compose`

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  sql.data:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine

  myapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: myapp/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sql.data
      - rabbitmq
```

- `docker-compose.override.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sql.data:
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Pass_word
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"

  rabbitmq:
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"

  myapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44376
    ports:
      - "61936:80"
      - "44376:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

Comment: Please share the compose files , looks like the issue is with how the container is configured when you run the integration test.

Comment: Sure, plz see my update.